# Mobile App Login/Password Security

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm making a mobile app that first requires the user to log in with a username and password. The password is hashed and sent to the server and some PHP checks to see that the hash and the username match.

That all works, fine and dandy. After the username/password checks out though, the user is able to access the rest of the pages in the app, which access server-side script without any kind of security checking. I'd like to change that.

Conventionally, I would imagine that the server should return a "token" (i.e. some randomized characters shared by the server and the client with no connection to the password hash itself) upon successfully logging in. Is it so simple as doing this, and checking/renewing the token expiration time each time the user accesses a new page? Or am I missing a vital part of the security process?

Comment: Make sure you submit the hash over SSL, since you're vulnerable to replay attacks.

Comment: So wait, if I intercept and save a user's hashed password, then I can log in as that user?

Comment: @GregHewgill You would be able to send a request to the server with the username and hashed password, which would probably give you a heart-warming "pass" message.

Comment: It seems to me that a password security system would want to avoid that kind of simple replay attack.

Comment: I will do some research on that. I'd also appreciate hearing your input on using tokens from page to page.